# What is a TCP wrapper and how do I use it?

Tags: security

What is a "TCP wrapper", and how can I use it to improve system security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TCP Wrapper is a host-based Networking ACL system, used to filter
>   network access to Internet. TCP wrappers was original written to
>   monitor and stop cracking activities on the UNIX workstation in 90s.
>   It was best solution in 90s to protect the UNIX workstations over the
>   Internet. However it has few disadvantages:
>
> 1. All UNIX apps must be compiled with the libwrap library.
> 2. The wrappers do not work with RPC services over TCP.
> 3. The user name lookup feature of TCP Wrappers uses identd to identify
>      the username of the remote host. By default, this feature is
>      disabled, as identd may appear hung when there are large number of
>      TCP connections.
>
> However, it has one strong advantage over firewall. It works on the
>   application layer. It can filter requests when encryption is used.
>   Basically, you need to use both host based and network based security.
>   Common services such as pop3, ftp, sshd, telnet, r-services are
>   supported by TCP Wrappers.

<sup>Source:[NIX CRAFT](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcp-wrappers-hosts-allow-deny-tutorial/)</sup>