# How to restrict ssh and ftp to certain ip address?

Tags: ssh, ftp, restricted-access

What is the easiest way to make it so that the only way anyone could access the ssh or ftp for my ubuntu machine is to be on a certain ip address?

Comment: tcpwrapper will do this very easily, /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny . See https://askubuntu.com/questions/407405/what-is-a-tcp-wrapper-and-how-do-i-use-it and https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcp-wrappers-hosts-allow-deny-tutorial/ . Not all services use tcp wrapper , but ssh and ftp both do, so simple set or rules. If you need rules we need more details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu Firewall (ufw).

See if Ubuntu Firewall is active:

```
$ sudo ufw status
```

If it's inactive, enable it:

```
$ sudo ufw enable
```

Allow SSH connections from a specific IP address:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 123.123.123.123 to any port 22 proto tcp
```

Allow FTP connections

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 123.123.123.123 to any port 21 proto tcp
```

View firewall rules:

```
$ sudo ufw status
```

Delete above SSH rule:

```
$ sudo ufw delete allow from 123.123.123.123 to any port 22 proto tcp
```

Disable Ubuntu Firewall:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: UFW is Uncomplicated FireWall. UFW isn't "active" it's a program one installs to write iptables rules more simply, a varnish if you will, that configures the netfilter firewall. `ufw enable` tells ufw to enable the firewall, for example.

Comment: Ah, ok. Good to know. I haven't looked at the documentation lately, but I've always called it "Ubuntu Firewall". I don't think [the author himself is too fussed about what UFW stands for:](https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/tree/README) _"What does it mean?  It has come to mean 'Uncomplicated Firewall', but you can change it to something more suitable if you want. If you like it, you might pick 'Universal Firewall', or 'Ultimate Firewall'. If you are not a fan, perhaps 'Unbearable Firewall'. Have fun!"_

Comment: How do I allow all connections from my local network? I have a dynamic ip so if I did the normal ip address it would eventually change and I'd be locked out. I've also tried using a DNS that points to my dyn ip but it gave an error "Bad source address".

Comment: If your LAN is 192.168.0.x, you can allow from all LAN addresses using: `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 22 proto tcp` - this is assuming your SSH server is on the LAN and you're trying to access it using the LAN IP address, not some external IP address that is forwarded to the LAN address.

Comment: @kevCAI you can put a netblock in, so have the allowed IP address swapped for your ISPs netblock; often that info can be found from `whois $ipaddress` where $ipaddress is your own IP.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is using the firewall. DigitalOcean has a great tutorial on [configuring ufw](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands).

First make sure ufw is enabled, if not enable it:

```
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw enable
```

The relevant command for ssh/ftp from one address would be

```
sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.15 to any port 22
sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.15 to any port 21
```

Port 22 is the defaut for SSH, 21 is the default for FTP. You can replace `15.15.15.15` by either a subnet you want or a specific IP.